# Newline in 8086 assembly language: my text prints stair-stepped

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm getting stair-step output like this
[image]

My program works correctly, except that when I print a new line, and then print something in the current line, it shows on the next line but with some space before it.

---

The program is this: (print a table of multiple numbers from 0 to 9):

```
data_seg segment
    I DB 0D
    J DB 0D
    R DB ?
    DIVER DB 10D
    data_seg ends

stack_seg segment
    stack_seg ends

code_seg segment
    MAIN proc far
        assume cs:code_seg, ds:data_seg, ss:stack_seg
        MOV AX,data_seg
        MOV DS,AX

        FOR1:
            MOV J,0D
            FOR2:
            MOV AX,0H
            MOV AL,I
            MUL J
            DIV DIVER 
            MOV R,AH
            ADD AL,48D
            MOV AH,0EH
            INT 10H
            MOV AL,R
            ADD AX,48D
            MOV AH,0EH
            INT 10H

            MOV AX,32D
            MOV AH,0EH
            INT 10H
            INC J 
            MOV AX,0
            MOV AL,J
            SUB AX,10D
            JNZ FOR2
         INC I
         MOV AX,10D
         MOV AH,0EH
         INT 10H
         MOV AX,0
         MOV AL,I
         SUB AX,10D
         JNZ FOR1

        MOV AX,4CH
        INT 21H
        MAIN endp
    code_seg ends
end MAIN
```

Comment: @jww: this is not `[windows]` code, it's DOS (for the `int 21h`), and using `int 10h` BIOS calls otherwise for some reason.

Comment: @Peter - No Microsoft tag; used Windows tag to indicate the platform.

Comment: @jww: The `[dos]` tag is the appropriate one here.  See my edit.  Nothing about this code has anything to do with Windows, other than the fact that some 32-bit versions of Windows come with a DOS virtual machine.  That's why there's a separate tag for DOS.

Comment: @Peter - The dollar sign terminator tells me it is Microsoft technologies. MASM used it for string termination. Doubtful it is DOS in 2011; 15 years too late.

Comment: @jww: not everything Microsoft has made is Windows.  DOS existed first, and is separate.  And `$` terminators started with CP/M, copied by DOS but *not* Windows.  (Windows uses 0-terminated C strings in low-level WinAPI functions like for filenames).  Also, the *question* doesn't use any DOS string functions, that's only in one of the answers, so it might not even be useful if the DOS exit call is just there to test bootloader code under DOS.  Anyway, if there was no DOS tag, your edit might have been justified (but creating a DOS tag would have been better).  But it's clearly wrong.

Comment: @Peter - Lol... DOS is dead. But keep believing folks are using it if it makes you happy.

Comment: @jww: DOS is still used to test newly-developed motherboards, and for some insane reason some schools (many in India) teach assembly language with 16-bit DOS.  Many of them with emu8086.  (Somewhat like MARS/SPIM GUI editor+debugger+simulator, but for 8086, including DOS).  I *wish* DOS was dead, but it's not.  It's embedded OS that gets out of the way, I can see the use-case.  https://www.freedos.org/ is still maintained, for use in embedded stuff apparently.  I have zero interest in DOS, but you clearly haven't spent much time looking in the `[x86]` tag if you think DOS is dead.

Comment: @jww: Literally all the DOS questions I've seen on SO are from beginners who are stuck with it for school, or for some reason picked it for self-teaching (although self-taught are usually "writing their own OS" as a legacy BIOS MBR bootloader, so x86-16 but not DOS, just BIOS calls).  But there's a significant volume of such questions.  The people who actually use DOS for testing engineering-sample mobos or other use-cases don't need to ask yet another duplicate about reading / printing multi-digit numbers or how `div` works on SO.

Comment: @jww: more importantly, you *can't* run this code on a modern 64-bit Windows system without an emulator like DOSBOX or BOCHs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to print new line *and* carriage return.

Answer (score 9):

if your using emu80x86 this code should do it

```
mov dx,13
  mov ah,2
  int 21h  
  mov dx,10
  mov ah,2
  int 21h
```

Answer (score 5):

This would print a new line:

1) Add in the data segment:

```
linefeed db 13, 10, "$"
```

2) And then use this anywhere you need a new line:

```
; new line
mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset linefeed
int 21h
```

Comment: this worked for me.. but what does linefeed db 13, 10, "$" exactly do ?

Answer (score 3):

AS anthony said, Based on your assembler, you need to do a carriage return and line feed to go to next line and place cursor at the beggining of the line. For MASM you can use Call crlf or print values 0dh and 0ah respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You got a stair-step output because in the code where you'd like to continue on another line, you only have send the control code 10 to the display:

> ```
> MOV AX,10D
> MOV AH,0EH
> INT 10H
> ```

On the DOS platform, the *New Line* is represented by **two bytes**: the first byte is called *Carriage Return* and it uses control code 13, and the second byte is called *Line Feed* and it uses control code 10.

This two-byte sequence mimics the action of the ancient typewriter, where you would pull a lever whenever you wanted to continue on the next line.
This lever performed a double action:

- first it would *Return* the *Carriage* to the left-side of the paper
- and then (while still maintaining the pull) the roller would turn a bit so as to *Feed* a new *Line*.

In BIOS it looks like:

```
mov  ax, 0E0Dh ; BIOS.Teletype
int  10h
mov  al, 10
int  10h
```

In DOS it looks like:

```
mov  dl, 13
mov  ah, 02h  ; DOS.PrintCharacter
int  21h      ; -> AL=13
mov  dl, 10
int  21h      ; -> AL=10
```

If your program already contains a string that ends in `13, 10, '$'` then move these 3 bytes to the following line, label the line suitably, and output the new line like:

```
mov  dx, crlf ; For MASM-type assemblers write `mov dx, offset crlf`
mov  ah, 09h  ; DOS.PrintString
int  21h      ; -> AL='$'

...

msg1 db 'stackoverflow rocks'
crlf db 13, 10, '$'
```

ps. Although we normally write 13 followed by 10, the emulator [emu8086](/questions/tagged/emu8086) seems to prefer 10 coming before 13. Could well be that it's one of its many bugs and not so much an intended choice of the designer(s).

---

The highly upvoted and accepted answer states:

> You need to print new line and carriage return

It's like saying "To print **new line**, you need to print **new line** and carriage return".

'New Line' is the name for the combined action, and 'Carriage Return' plus 'Line Feed' are its constituents.

Even on a platform where the carriage return code (13) is not required, you would say: "To print *new line*, you need to print the *linefeed* code (10)".

Answer (score 0):

in emu8086 you can use this function:

```
newLine PROC FAR
MOV AH, 2
MOV DL, 10
INT 21H
MOV DL, 13
INT 21H
RET
newLine endp
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue while studying assembly in the class, I could fix it using the `cert` code which is in my case 0D and the exact same code for carriage return.

Answer (score -3):

try to put lanes for line return

```
mov ax, 4c00h ; return to ms-dos
int 21h
```