# How to express '\n' in Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

I would like to express '\n' as an Assembly code!!

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hi! My name is Joe.\n I'm 11 years old");

    return 0;
}
```

How to express '\n' part in Assembly?

Comment: the [same way](https://godbolt.org/z/PBC6R3), or alternatively you can use its ASCII code `0x0A`

Comment: If you are looking for an answer related to a processor emulator, most probably [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374034/newline-in-8086-assembly-language-my-text-prints-stair-stepped):

Comment: Which assembler do you use?  What architecture are you programming for?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the particular assembler you are using, but in some (including GAS: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Characters.html), it is still `\n`, just like C. You can see what the assembly looks like in a number of different ways, but these days GodBolt is pretty nice.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZLq3Kn

```
.LC0:
        .string "Hi! My name is Joe.\n I'm 11 years old"
```

You can see that the string looks the same. In GAS, `.string` creates a 0-terminated string. If you change to Clang (which uses the same syntax but makes different choices about which directives to emit), you'll see it uses `.asciz`.

```
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Hi! My name is Joe.\n I'm 11 years old"
```

But in both assemblers, `\n` is the same.

**Not all assemblers support this syntax.** But many do. Check the manual for your assembler.

`.string` is the same as `.asciz` on most targets, both appending a zero.  [The manual says](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/String.html) that in GAS syntax for some ISAs, `.string` might not append a zero, while [`.asciz`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Asciz.html) always does and `.ascii` never does.  The `z` stands for zero.

Answer (score 2):

To express `\n` in assembler, especially `nasm` assembler (pointing comment from **dvhh**) you can use `0x0a`.

Example :

```
string1 db "Hi! My name is Joe.", 0x0a
string2 db "I'm 11 years old.", 0x0a
```

Comment: and in in some assemblers you can continue the string on the same line.

Comment: Note that these strings do *not* have a 0 terminator.  For that, append a `,0` to `db`'s list of byte elements, after the `0xa` or `\`\n\``.  (NASM but not YASM supports C-style escapes inside backticks)

Answer (score 1):

In NASM syntax, C-style escapes are processed inside backticks, so you can write `\n` as an integer constant with value 0xa = 10

```
mov byte [mem], `\n`

newline: equ `\n`        ; or 0xa or 10, but not '\n' or "\n"

str1: db `Hello\n`
str2: db 'Hello', 0xa   ; exactly identical to str1
```

See [the manual](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2).

For the GNU assembler, see [its manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Chars.html): `'\n'` works, like `movb $'\n', (%rdi)`